# Forefront (Identity Manager/Sync Service) missing from Service Manager

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, forefront

I am building a new testing environment, and in the process I have noticed that the Forefront services are missing from the Service Manager. Is there a way to add these services? This is the first time I have seen these missing. I am a local admin on the server. We are running Server 2008 R2 Enterprise with SP1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've seen this before.  Running a Install-SPService fixed it for me - http://sharepoint.nauplius.net/2011/06/missing-user-profile-synchronization.html.

Comment: while the previous suggestion got the service running again, running Install-SPService got the job done as well

Answer (score 2):

Jason,

May be this is of help to you:
[On a SharePoint 2010 box Forefront services is missing from the services console](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/vedvyas/on-a-sharepoint-2010-box-forefront-services-is-missing-from-the-services-console)

Extract from blog:

> For User Profile service application we require following service in
> the services.msc.
>
> - Forefront Identity Manager Service.
> - Forefront Identity synchronization Manage Service.
>
> The above service gets provisioned when we services are provisioned. I
> my case I found both the Forefront services was missing.
>
> Later after further research found that following registry keys were
> missing from the SharePoint box, due to this Forefront services was
> missing from the services.msc.
>
> Missing registry Key:
>
> HKLM\System\Controlset1\FIMService
>
> HKLM\System\Controlset2\FIMService
>
> HKLM\System\CurrentControlset\FIMService
>
> HKLM\System\Controlset1\FIMSynchronizationService
>
> HKLM\System\Controlset2\FIMSynchronizationService
>
> HKLM\System\CurrentControlset\FIMSynchronizationService
>
> Exported the above registry Keys from working SharePoint 2010 box and
> imported in to the Problematic SharePoint 2010 box were we have issue
> starting User Profile service application.
>
> **Note:- Before making any registry changes ensure we take a backup of
> the registry.**
>
> After importing the registry key reboot the machine and then you would
> find the both the Forefront services
>
> - Forefront Identity Manager Service.
> - Forefront Identity synchronization Manage Service.

Comment: this solution works as well, not something our system engineers were excited about though

Comment: Yeah messing up registries isn't preferred... Above answer seems to be idealistic!